# Jquery: Insert div after first image/first image's div

Tags: jquery, html

I am having a div.

```
<div id="div1">some content</div>
```

and a div element like below having img element

```
<div><img src="url"/> </div>
some text
```

or 
a div element having hyperlink on the image tag

```
<div><a href="url"><img src="url"/></a></div>
some text
```

How can i achieve to get the below output using jquery

```
<div><img src="url"/> </div>
<div id="div1">some content</div>
some text
```

or

```
<div><a href="url"><img src="url"/></a></div>
<div id="div1">some content</div>
some text
```

Comment: Did you try jquery insertBefore. http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/

Comment: Hey Rocky, please review the answers and click `✔` button (on the left side) if you think the answer is correct. This is how StackOverflow works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.after()` jQuery method:

```
$("div").after('<div id="div1">some content</div>');
```

This will add `some content` div *after* **all** `div`s.

Probably you need a better (more specific) jQuery selector, maybe like this:

```
$("div > img").parent().after('<div id="div1">some content</div>');
```

---

> ### [`after(content [, content])`](http://api.jquery.com/after/)
>
> Insert content, specified by the parameter, **after** each element in the set of matched elements.

---

### Demo

```js
$("div").after('<div id="div1">some content</div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href="url">
    <img src="url" />
  </a>
</div>
some text
```